# Creating and iterating through a 3D array

Tags: c++, arrays, 3d

Here is my 3D array iteration. I'm having trouble receiving a desired sample output:

**Enter seed: 22
6 11 4
Error. Invalid array index.**

Where exactly would I have to put the cout statement "Error. Invalid array index."? for it to match the output above?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>



using namespace std;

int main(){

int seed;
unsigned int x,y,z;
int sum = 0;

// prompt user for seed
cout << "Enter seed: ";
cin >> seed;

// initiate rand function
srand(seed);
int arr[10][10][10];
for(int z = 0; z < 10; z++){
   for(int y = 0; y < 10; y++){
       for(int x = 0; x < 10; x++){
           arr[z][y][x] = rand() % 1000;
       }
     }
  }


cout << "Enter an index for x, y, and z: ";
cin >> x >> y >> z ;

while((x < 1 && x > 10 ) || (y < 1 && y > 10 ) || (z < 1 && z > 10 ) ){
   cin >> x >> y >> z;
}

for(unsigned int a = x; a < 10; a++){
   sum += arr[a][y][z];
}

for(int j = y + 1; j < 10; j++){
   if (y >= 10)
   {
    cout << "Error. Invalid array index.";
   }
   else if (y < 10)
   {
    sum += arr[x][j][z];
   }
 }

 for(int k = z + 1; z < 10; z++){
   sum += arr[x][y][k];
 }


 cout << sum << endl;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you serious? You want us to do your homework? Please, show us a little more effort.

Comment: It works fine for me. Which values causes this problem?

Comment: Helping me on where to put one line of code does not constitute "Doing my Homework". I did this entire code myself I believe that is more than enough effort.

Answer (score 0):

Not that 0 should be also valid, but in your code it doesn't, so in my sample it doesn't too.

It can be something like this:

```
do{
  cout << "Enter an index for x, y, and z: ";
  cin >> x >> y >> z ;
  if((x > 0 && x < 10 ) && (y > 0 && y < 10 ) && (z > 0 && z < 10 ))
     break;
  else
    cout<<"Invalid array index"<<endl;

} while(1);
```

Comment: This helps tremendously but what would be a good termination function after you type in the index for x, y, and z? I would like the compiler to terminate after I type in "6 11 4" instead of using a while loop(1) prompting me to keep entering in index until it holds true. I just started C++ so sorry if my computer lingo isn't up to par.

Comment: it is up to you, you don't have to use a loop, i just tried to use your idea, and you set it in a loop. with or without a loop, the if should shows good input(without loop the break is error) and the else should shows bad input.

Answer (score 0):

Your while loop looks suspect.

```
while((x < 1 && x > 10 ) || (y < 1 && y > 10 ) || (z < 1 && z > 10 ) ){
   cin >> x >> y >> z;
}
```

None of those conditions will ever be true. You can't have `y > 10 && y < 1` ever be true. So you need to reconsider that logic.

In addition, your code strictly specifies that the array is indexed from 0...9 (10 elements) at each level. So you need to ensure that you're validating around the correct numbers.

```
while(x < 0 || x >= 10 || y < 0 || y >= 10 || z < 0 || z >= 10) {
    cout << "Error. Invalid array index." << endl;
    cin >> x >> y >> z;
}
```